# How to make a similar cast like 1LL with any other type?

Tags: c++, types, casting

Does this make any sense?

```
    static_cast<long long>(1) == 1LL
    static_cast<float>(1) =? 1F
```

Is there a short way of making the casting for other types such as float?
Thank you very much!

Comment: No, makes no sense. Are you talking about type suffixes in literals like 1LL or 1.0F?

Answer (score 8):

Since C++11 you could define your own literals. For example, you could define literal `_F` like this:

```
float operator"" _F(unsigned long long l)
{
    return static_cast<float>(l);
}

int main()
{
    auto a = 1_F;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), float>::value, "Not a float");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This answer describes C++11. User-defined literals, and some of the types, didn't exist in historic versions of the language.

Integer literals can end with nothing, `L`, `LL`, `U`, `UL` or `ULL` giving a type of `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` respectively. These can be in lower case if you like; and the actual type may be wider than specified if necessary to represent the value.

Floating-point literals can end with nothing, `F` or `L` giving a type of `double`, `float` or `long double` respectively. Again, these can be in lower case if you like.

Character and string literals can begin with nothing, `u`, `U` or `L`, giving a character type of `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t` or `wchar_t` respectively. Strings can also begin with `u8` to indicate a `char` character type with UTF-8 encoding.

You can also define your own *user-defined literals* to make literals of any type, if you find weird things like `123_km` more readable than `kilometres(123)`. I don't see the point of that, but someone's posted an example if you're interested.